# Add sublists to ArrayList with for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, alphabetical

I'm trying to make a method that removes all words within the alphabetical range of two strings. The parameters I've given should remove basically everything, but this is my output:

[and, my, friends]

I really don't understand why???

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("hello");
        stringList.add("and");
        stringList.add("welcome");
        stringList.add("my");
        stringList.add("little");
        stringList.add("friends");
        System.out.println(stringList);
        removeInRange(stringList, "abc", "zen");
    }

    public static void removeInRange(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String start, String end) {
        char startChar = start.charAt(0);
        char endChar = end.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            Character target = arrayList.get(i).charAt(0);
            for (char c = startChar; c <= endChar; c++) { 
                if (target.equals(c)) {
                    arrayList.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use indexing as part of the iteration as you are removing from the list and changing `i` when selecting `arrayList.get(i)`

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an element from an ArrayList, all the indices of the elements following it are decremented by one. You have to account for that in your loop :

For example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        Character target = arrayList.get(i).charAt(0);
        for (char c = startChar; c <= endChar; c++) { 
            if (target.equals(c)) {
                arrayList.remove(i);
                i--; // this would make sure you don't skip any element in the list
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eran is correct, but the detection for characters can be improved, without using a for-loop for the character check. Use of `if (target >= startChar && target <= endChar)` would be a small improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go through the list backwards. 
I won't tell why for now in case you want to figure it out on your own ... If you can't, ask :)

Comment: why? It answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: true, but your answer is more a comment, a suggestion, not a SO answer.

Comment: @KarelG When you hover your mouse over `add comment` link, there is a message that says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. *Avoid answering questions in comments*."

This is not  a "suggestion", but a direct answer to the OP's question why their code is not working. 


Also, whoever voted this answer down, can you please explain how do you think it is not useful? Is it incorrect? Unclear? Irrelevant?